# Remover os colchetes da função sorted()

Tags: python

Estava criando uma calculadora de função quadrática e queria dispor as raízes na ordem crescente. Pesquisando, cheguei à função `sorted()`.

```
raiz1 = round((-b + math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a), 2)
raiz2 = round((-b - math.sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a), 2)

raizes = [raiz1, raiz2]

if delta > 0:
    print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: {sorted(raizes, key=int)}.")
```

O resultado disso é que vou ter as raízes dentro de colchetes, ao invés de parênteses, como é o padrão. Eu sei que isso não é grande problema, mas eu penso que no futuro haverão situações em que eu não vou querer os números dentro de colchetes, por isso eu gostaria de saber se tem algum jeito de suprimi-los.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) retorna uma [lista](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), e quando você imprime uma lista, os elementos são mostrados entre colchetes, então não é que "*`sorted` retorna os colchetes*", é que os colchetes fazem parte da **representação textual** de uma lista, ou seja, a maneira que foi escolhida para mostrar uma lista em forma de texto (mas os colchetes em si não fazem parte da lista, pois ela só tem os valores).

Se não quer que mostre os colchetes, então não imprima a lista diretamente. Uma alternativa é transformar a lista em uma única string, usando [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), e aí você coloca os parênteses em volta dela:

```
print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: ({', '.join(map(str, sorted(raizes, key=int)))}).")
```

Repare nos parênteses antes e depois de `{` e `}`: eles ficarão em volta da string gerada por `join`. No caso, `join` vai colocar os valores separados por `,`  (vírgula e espaço - e você pode trocar pelo que quiser).

Ou, para deixar um pouco mais claro o que está acontecendo:

```
raizes_texto = ', '.join(map(str, sorted(raizes, key=int)))
print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: ({raizes_texto}).")
```

No caso, também usei [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) juntamente com [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) para transformar os valores em strings, pois o `join` dá erro se os elementos não forem strings.

---

Acho que não faz muito sentido usar `key=int`, pois aí você estará ordenando as raízes pelos seus valores inteiros. Então se você tiver:

```
raizes = [2.5, 2.4]
```

Ao transformá-las em `int`, ambas serão igual a `2`, então elas não mudarão de ordem, pois a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted) diz que a ordenação é estável, ou seja, não muda a ordem de 2 elementos se eles forem considerados iguais. Portanto, da forma que você fez, as raízes não serão ordenadas caso elas tenham valores com casas decimais. Se quer ordená-las, use apenas `sorted` e pronto:

```
raizes_texto = ', '.join(map(str, sorted(raizes)))
print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: ({raizes_texto}).")
```

---

Outra alternativa é transformar a lista em uma [tupla](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#tuple), pois tuplas, ao serem impressas, mostram os elementos entre parênteses:

```
print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: {tuple(sorted(raizes))}.")
```

Se bem que essa eu acho meio "gambiarra" (assim como soluções que fazem `replace` dos colchetes, ou qualquer outra coisa que dependa da implementação específica de como a lista é impressa). Um `replace` pode parecer "inocente" e até funcionar para este caso específico, mas basta você ter uma lista em que um dos elementos é uma string cujo texto contém um colchete, para tudo parar de funcionar (ou uma lista de listas, pois as listas internas também são impressas com colchetes e estes serão removidos indevidamente, [veja um exemplo](https://ideone.com/fsgiuc)).

Enfim, se quer um formato específico, então construa a string explicitamente, de acordo com o que você quer.

Answer (score 3):

Existem várias formas de fazer isso.

Você pode criar uma variável que recebe o retorno da função `sorted` e então acessar os índices do array:

```
raizes = [10, 5]

raizesParaExibir = sorted(raizes)

print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: {raizesParaExibir[0]} e {raizesParaExibir[1]}.")
```

Seguindo a mesma lógica, você pode ordenar a lista `raizes` com o método `sort` e então acessar os índices:

```
raizes = [10, 5]

raizes.sort()

print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: {raizes[0]} e {raizes[1]}.")
```

Podemos transformar a lista em uma string e remover os colchetes com o método `strip`:

```
raizes = [10, 5]

print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: {str(sorted(raizes)).strip('[]')}.")
```

Novamente, seguindo essa lógica, podemos remover os colchetes utilizando o método `replace`:

```
raizes = [10, 5]

print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: {str(sorted(raizes)).replace('[', '').replace(']', '')}.")
```

Como ultimo exemplo, podemos utilizar o método `join` da string em conjunto com a função `map`:

```
raizes = [10, 5]

print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: {', '.join(map(lambda x: str(x), sorted(raizes)))}.")
```

---

> Veja todos esses exemplos online: https://repl.it/repls/SeagreenGiddyBruteforceprogramming

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função `join`

```
print(f"A função tem duas raízes reais, que são: {','.join(str(v) for v in sorted(raizes, key=int))}.")
```

Na alteração acima, primeiro a lista retornada pelo `sorted` tem seus valores convertidos em strings. Depois a função `join` concatena os valores do `iterable` resultante.