# Receber itens de uma lista ordenado em uma variável - Python

Tags: python, lista

Boa tarde, pessoal!

Comecei a estudar Python recentemente, e tenho uma dúvida que pode parecer básica mas tá me complicando.

Eu queria receber os itens de uma lista em uma variável de forma ordenada.

Por exemplo:

Tenho uma lista:

```
num = [2,5,7,9]
```

Como recebo esses itens em uma variável, tipo:

```
var = num
print(var)
```

E a saída ser 2579, e não [2, 5, 7, 9] como está sendo.

Comment: Não compreendi bem... Criei um exemplo e funcionou parece que como você espera, dê uma olhada: https://repl.it/repls/ReflectingHummingTriangle

Comment: Sim, ele recebe a lista na variavel VAR e imprime ela. Eu queria receber só os itens.
Pra então, na hora de printar, ao invés de printar [2,5,7,9], que é o que ele recebe, imprimir só os itens dela fora de uma lista, tipo 2579.

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [Remover os colchetes da função sorted()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443936/remover-os-colchetes-da-fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-sorted)

Comment: Não responde exatamente, mas me ajudou entender que há outras possibilidades, como transformar em uma tupla. Muito obrigado cara!

Answer (score 3):

## TL;DR

```py
nums = [2, 5, 7, 9]

valor = "".join(nums)
print(valor)  # "2579"
```

## Motivo

Ao verificar a [documentação da função `print`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) você observará a seguinte frase:

> All non-keyword arguments are converted to strings like `str()` does and written to the stream...

Tradução livre:

> Todos os argumentos não-nomeados são convertidos para strings como `str()` faz e depois escritos no *stream*...

Ou seja, `print(lista)` tem o mesmo resultado de `print(str(lista))`<sup>*</sup> pois é realizada a conversão da lista para string. Você pode verificar que `str([1, 2, 3]) == '[1, 2, 3]'`, ou seja, uma string que contém os elementos da lista separados por `", "` e envoltos em colchetes.

<sup>** Em teoria devem ser sempre os mesmo resultados, porém não realizei testes com todos os tipo nativos e classes customizadas.*</sup>

Portanto, para personalizar a maneira como você quer mostrar sua lista, basta acessá-la elemento por elemento ou usando métodos específicos.

## Usando `str.join()`

O método [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) une os elementos de um iterável de strings e concatena com um separador.

Como sua lista é de inteiros, será necessário converter os valores para string antes de usar o método `str.join()`. Você pode fazer isso usando `map` (`string = map(str, nums)`) ou *list comprehensions* (`string = [str(n) for n in nums]`).

Ex.:

```py
nums = [2, 5, 7, 9]

valor = "".join(str(n) for n in nums)
print(valor)  # "2579"

demo_2 = "-".join(map(str, nums))
print(demo_2)  # "2-5-7-9"

demo_3 = ", ".join(map(str, nums))
print(demo_3)  # "2, 5, 7, 9"
```

## Usando `print()`

Você pode printar elemento por elemento sem espaços entre eles usando o parâmetro `end` da função [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print):

```py
nums = [2, 5, 7, 9]

for n in nums:
    print(n, end="")  # "2579"

for n in nums:
    print(n, end="-")  # "2-5-7-9"

for n in nums:
    print(n, end=", ")  # "2, 5, 7, 9"
```

Comment: Estou formulando uma explicação melhor, mas por enquanto deixo as soluções acima.

Comment: Nossa, foi uma ótima explicação, muito obrigado! Agora eu sei que tem como converter os itens em uma string.

Tentei transforma-la em uma string com:
num = [2, 5, 7, 9]

var = "".join(num)
print(var)

Mas ele me retorna "TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found"
Será que é algo de sintaxe que eu posso ter errado?

Comment: Retificando:
Deu certo, amigo. Era só a falta de alguns atributos.

Fiz assim:
valor = "".join(map(str,nums))
print(valor)

E aí deu certo!

Comment: Foi falha minha, os números da lista devem ser convertidos. Sua solução com `map` funciona

Answer (score 0):

Outra forma de se obter o resultado desejado pelo autor da pergunta é utilizando a combinação da função **[map()](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#map)** com a expressão **[lambda](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3.8/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions)**. Dessa forma o seguinte código pode ser implementado:

```
num = [2, 5, 7, 9]

r = ''.join(map(lambda i: str(i), num))

print(r)
```